# read response of http request

Tags: javascript, http, meteor, response

This may looks silly but I don't understand why is this happening

sinple http request

```
HTTP.get(url, {}, function(e,r){
      console.log(e, r);
      if(e){
        toastr.error("Invalid withdraw address, please check the address and try again");
        return;
      }else{
        console.log(r, r.statusCode,r.data.isValid, r.isValid);
        var d = r.data;
        console.log(d, d.isValid);
        if( r.statusCode === 200 &&  r.data.isValid ){

         }else{
            toastr.error("Invalid withdraw address, please check the address and try again");
            return;
         }
         $('#withdrawModal').modal('hide');
      }
    });
```

I'm not able to read response

[image]

I want to read "isVerify" value in the response, I tried all the possibilities but I'm getting undefined

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm using meteor http package, i'm getting response

Comment: it looks like the "isvalid" data is stored as json string under property "content" ?

Comment: Since the proposed answer seems to have solved OP's issue (`isValid` instead of `isvalid`), I am flagging this as off-topic because it was caused by a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response contains `isvalid`, but you are logging `isValid`.  Those two names are different.